# Ajax is not loading php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax code:

```
function saveChanges(object){ 
  var id = object.value;
  alert('HI'+id);
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ajaxChangeProfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id':id}
  });
}
```

Here is where it is being called

```
<select onchange="saveChanges(this);" name="changeChar" id="changeChar">
```

So when I change the value of the select box, I get the alert which contains the correct message and id.

At the top of the php file I am trying to send to I have a query which will add a number to a test table in my database, but this is not being added.

All I need to do in the php file is change 2 session variables and make 1 mySQL query.

Thanks

EDIT 1:

```
function saveChanges(object){ 

  var id = object.value;
  alert('HI'+id);
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ajaxChangeProfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id':id},
    success: function() {
      alert('WORKING');
    }
  });
}
```

I tried adding the done() callback, but it stopped the alert working, so I wasn't sure what to do, with the success added the message still displays but still doesn't load the page. Is it okay only having an alert in the success or do I need something else?

EDIT 2:

```
function saveChanges(object){ 

  var id = object.value;
  alert('HI'+id);
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ajaxChangeProfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id':id},
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

I have made the changed suggested by the answerer, still the same issue, the first alert is being shown, with the correct id, but then nothing on the php file is happening.

Comment: Do you have any of the PHP code to show us? And @bcesars is correct about needing a success.

Comment: add a `done()` callback and see what the response contains

`$.ajax({
    url : 'ajaxChangeProfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id':id}
  }).done(data){
     console.log(data);
  };`

Comment: And also a `fail` too. Or check the console for errors in the network requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply both of you, does it matter what I put in the success part bcesars? Could I just have an alert? And itamar, which php code would you like to see? The php I'm linking to or the php on the origional page?

Comment: I have added a success in my edit, I tried adding the done() code that you posted gibsonman507, but it stopped the alert working, which worried me. Thanks for your replies so far!

Comment: I would inspect POST data on XHR call of PHP page... (Using Developer Tools on Chrome, for example...). If it contains the data id you send, then the problem is on PHP side; otherwise it's on the JavaScript side...

Answer (score 0):

in your success function you aren't returning the data. try adding the error function as well.

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error){
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply eg_dac, I still am having the same issue though.

Comment: If you have any issues from request @Waq, try so analyze the response inside browser.
Perhaps you see any error in your PHP script which is recomended you post it inside your question.

Comment: yeah use your dev tools, and check the network panel. It will reveal if your php page has an error, or what data is passed back. your php may be returning 404 or 500 errors. check my answer edit.

Comment: Thanks you two, I'll have a look about to see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery Onchange event

```
<select name="changeChar" id="changeChar"></select>
```

In javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeChar').change.(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        alert('HI'+id);
        var datastring = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
           url : 'ajaxChangeProfile.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: datastring,
           success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
           }
        });    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this didn't work for me though, the first alert didn't show up.